# VBA write excel function in a cell containing a defined variable

Tags: excel, vba, function, variables

I'm a newcomer on this site, found a lot of solutions in the past as a passive reader, but now I'm stuck with something in VBA.

So, I want to write in excel in a specific cell, a formula that calls a function (already in my code). I want it to be written as a formula, and not just as a result.

The function that I call is the interpolate function.

When I write this piece of code, it works :

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 8).Formula = "=Interpolate(J11:J43,K11:K46,F3,FALSE)"
```

Now, I want to make a part of the formula variable

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 8).String = "=Interpolate(J11:J"&Lastrow1&",K11:K46,F3,FALSE)"
```

In my code `Lastrow1 = 43` and is undefined

I also tried this, no chance

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 8).String = "=Interpolate(J11:J""&Lastrow1&"",K11:K46,F3,FALSE)"
```

Or this :

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 8).String = "=Interpolate(J11:J"""&Lastrow1&""",K11:K46,F3,FALSE)"
```

Any help on how to do that ?

I tried using this piece of code

Dim Lastrow1 as long

Lastrow1 = 43

Worksheets("YourSheetName").Cells(2, 8).Formula = "=Interpolate(J11:J""&Lastrow1&"",K11:K46,F3,FALSE)"

It doesn't work neither, I have the error message "Application-defined or object-defined error".

Comment: Just to clarify, you want it to be rendered in the cell as the text of the formula, not the result? Also, are you getting any kind of error message? your question isn't completely clear.

Comment: Also show how you defined your variables, as that can be of major influence. (local vs global mainly)

Comment: Dim lastrow1 As Long
Lastrow1 = 43
Worksheets("YourSheetName").Cells(2, 8).Formula = "=Interpolate(J11:J""&Lastrow1&"",K11:K46,F3,FALSE)"

returns "Application-defined or object-defined error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Cells(2, 8).Formula`.

Try to stay away from `ActiveSheet`, instead use the qualifed version `Worksheets("YourSheetName").Cells(2, 8).Formula`...

Try the little piece of code to demonstrate how to get it to work:

```
Sub FormulaLastRow()

Dim Lastrow1 As Long

Lastrow1 = 43  ' <-- just for tests  
Worksheets("TEST").Cells(2, 8).Formula = "=Interpolate(J11:J" & Lastrow1 & ",K11:K46,F3,FALSE)"    

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your code doesn't work neither 

Worksheets("YourSheetName").Cells(2, 8).Formula = "=Interpolate(J11:J""&Lastrow1&"",K11:K46,F3,FALSE)" returns an "Application-defined or object-defined error".

Removing the double brackets, I get another error

Worksheets("YourSheetName").Cells(2, 8).Formula = "=Interpolate(J11:J"&Lastrow1&",K11:K46,F3,FALSE)" returns a "Syntax error"

Comment: @JeromeVBA you need to replace "YourSheetName" with the sheet's name where you want to have these formula. or, you can use `ActiveSheet` , which is not recommended

Comment: yes that's what I did, I replaced YourSheetName for the illustration here. I tried activesheet also, no chance.

Comment: @JeromeVBA write as a comment here below, the exact 2-3 line you are using and getting an error

Comment: Ok, so my sheet name is "TEST" and LastRow1=43 

My code is : 

Dim Lastrow1 as Long

Lastrow1 = 43

Worksheets("TEST").Cells(2, 8).Formula = "=Interpolate(J11:J""&Lastrow1&"",K11:K46,F3,FALSE)"

error = "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: @JeromeVBA if you copy my edited code (updated just now), exactly as it is and run it, it should work just fine

Comment: It works indeed, the mistake I was doing, was actually to double the brackets, OR to leave the single brackets but without space between the " and the & (giving a syntax error). Case solved, thanks very much for the swift reply and your patience.